# Google Endpoints and Public Api Key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

To use a Google service you can use OAuth authentication, or, if you don't need to log the user in, you can use a public api key, defining authorized domain as origin of the request.
Now, I'm writing my own API using google endpoints and I will allow users to use my APIs with a public api key, and not using OAuth, there are any built-in method to do so in GAE, or I have to write my own code to verify the api key and the origin of the request to my APIs?

Comment: Don't you really want your own oauth provider ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a client key you can limit those who can access your API by defining a list of referrers in the google console, if you are using the server API key you can limit it by defining a list of IP's which I believe can't be done with GAE since we don't no the server IP which can be changed any time.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean (what exact steps) by "defining a list of referrers in the Google Console" in the context of Google Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: Go to console.developers.google.com/project/apps~"your-app-id"/apiui/credential

under Public API access you will see Key for server applications and Key for browser applications for the server key you can define a list of allowed IP's and for the browser key you define a list of allowed referers.

Comment: +1 If I now obtain an API key an let my iOS client assign it to `service.APIKey` my (Java-based) service issues the following exception even before the `@ApiMethod` is called: `Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.` Under APIs I see all of Google's APIs, but not my own. So how can I configure API-key-based access in this case?

Comment: What API you are trying to use?

Comment: @moontss A service with a Google Cloud Endpoints interface, i.e. "my" (a custom) API.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use authentication, you don't need to provide api key I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I found a solution, i'm not sure is really secure. Here is the solution :

I have somthing working with :
 - an OAuth crédentials create on API console
 - My cilent ID (given when you create your credentials) in only in my server side code.
 - An end point constructed with this client ID.
 - I didn't check the button that 'active oauth authentification' on my app engine application.
Result :
  - Evry user can send data without any identification.
  - Evrybody can call evry methodo of the webservice by calling gapi.client.xxxx.list in the browser console --> so i remove forbidden method from the API End point.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out how to do this for the current GCP console. [Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys#calling_an_api_using_an_api_key) seems to be lacking the important step of enabling access to your own API in the project it is in.

This is what Google's docs say:

> **Create one API key for all callers**
>
> When you don't need to distinguish
>   between callers of your API, and you don't need to add API
>   restrictions, but you still want to require an API key (to prevent
>   anonymous access, for example), you can create one API key for all
>   callers to use.
>
> To create one API key for all callers:
>
> 1. In either the project that your API is configured in, or a project that your API is enabled in, create an API key for all caller.
> 2. Give the same API key to every caller.

The missing step 0 is to [enable the private API](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/enable-api) in your project. The steps for which are:

1. In the GCP Console, go to [APIs & services](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis) for your project.
2. On the Library page, click Private APIs.
3. Click the API you want to enable.
4. In the page that displays information about the API, click Enable.

Then step 1.5 is to restrict the API key to only access your private API. Now that you have enabled this API you'll see it as one of the options for API restriction on the key edit page.